# How to push an object into an array with typescript

Tags: typescript

i have an array name dish and have a form. After the form submited, data push to dish. I have tried to use push method to add that into an array, but it's have error. How i can do that with typescript ? 
Thanks you very much.
Class object.

```
export interface Dish {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   image: string;
   category: string;
   label: string;
   price: string;
   featured: boolean;
   description: string;
   comments: Comment[];
}
```

I have created an object name commentData from class comment to receive all data from form after submit. I also created an object name dish from class Dish. How to push object commentData to object dish.comments

```
export interface Comment {
   rating: number;
   comment: string;
   author: string;
   date: string;
}
```

My git : https://github.com/zymethyang/Ionic_HKUST

Comment: Please add a code  about your objects.

Comment: I have edited my post. Please check on  top. Thank you.

Answer (score 28):

```
let myArray = [];
let commentData = {} as Dish;
commentData.id = 3;
commentData.name = 'something';
myArray.push(commentData);
```

It will work...

Comment: Sorry, but i have a new comments and want to pushed to the existing dish.comments.

Answer (score 8):

## #Answer

Answer on how to push `Comment` (object) into `Dish.comments` (array) in TypeScript.

```js
export interface Dish {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   image: string;
   category: string;
   label: string;
   price: string;
   featured: boolean;
   description: string;
   // comments: Comment[]; // remove this
   comments: Array<Comment>; // <--- change to this. everytime you want to add array use Array<YourInterface>
}

export interface Comment {
   rating: number;
   comment: string;
   author: string;
   date: string;
}

dish.comments.push(commentData);
```

View live code on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEBsEsGMGtQCUCqA5UAXA9qAbtAKYDuWAFoaAE6EDOArpJgIQCwAUB9AHaaFUAzAIaxKAEWi0yoAN4dQC6ABMAXKG70AtgCN+AbnkLuQzYTW1MVHgHMD7BaGiah1s6AtXutw6FhC+1thUAJ7mljZ2DpBCupBhnt72CgAOVqLxET4ChP70NKqg2tjYkDnckQpKdLBWyZjQ2NwZXhWgIL7Ymqa8tGrgnd2YANoAunptYDSa2HiUmGSSPrADhD1qAIJUVELBADz9XauYAPoAfOPtuwC0N75kQl5zuPOSAHSghLMh9aagwdj0UDEB6YLC4IRKJSgIRbHagei0SibbZ7ACaAKoAElePxhKJThwAL4cDjtABEB0GZMctFAqTo-FmUOIQShPFAABVgslCABlGrQOqgAAK0WC1ioAO4UNouGIlG4hEIUJwdwerlAFJWvGpqq1h14xzJXBxghElEpR2Osh823qXjUGh0+iW2swzUSDiE9HmQQ9rSU-jcHky7GJnHYpVBSkkZDUEikoAAvDakso1ABGAA0hmMpjUAHIAEL0ATCSC4cALBCrUAAdRstALObTzlchbImEwyV6IEIAA8TMlSq9lppgE4XIRXskvM3DH4AkFQqACxztjH6o0hJBQOtTGkHqAExQmy2FNFYoX9-w4EeT3R50lUnA3AWACQZgCcry-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-fwQOYG9n3fewyyaSU04VtYj1a19QA) and click **RUN**.

As you see in the above code. You need to change `Comment[]` into `Array<Comment>`.

## #Explanation

### Generic Type Variables

`Array<T>` or `Array<Type>`

You may already be familiar with this style of type from other languages such as Java and C#.

We have Generic Type Variables in typescript too.

**Another way to use Generic Type Variables:**

Here's an example of an array with multiple types:

```js
let x: Array<string | number>
x = ["hello", "world", 2]
```

This second version is common if your array consists of different types of objects. For example:

```js
interface Boat {
  name: string
}

interface SpaceShip {
  code: number
}

interface Wagon {
  active: boolean
}

let inventory: Array<Boat | SpaceShip | Wagon> = [];

let boatData: Boat = {
  name: "Boat 1"
}

let spaceShipData: SpaceShip = {
  code: 1234
}

let wagonData: Wagon = {
  active: true
}

inventory.push(boatData);
inventory.push(spaceShipData);
inventory.push(wagonData);

console.log(inventory);
```

View live code on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=24#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHs5mQbwLABQyyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5oQL6GGiSyIoDKADj14ALYP1yFiCdABMqJAK5kARtFbsCnaPCTIA6nEboQEoskRhgAN3nL06ADYQ4IdQUJPsoG+HRQAntQAglBQcP4APBhYyAA+yAJCouLxBkYgAHzIALzIANoAugDcGp7IdlgAIlhw1NHYufhmpBTUAET1yACMbW4eENg0gkgiYtVgtQnDEKPijZLI0nLUXQBMAMwALH0EZQDuhsbjk2nGOabEFtby9AoQO94QvgEAdPwKNMIAFBVgxwCUJU0IB8YD8-jeH2+QySYxqgI4IKeYNe70+XwO6QBQMI0hANEcEBeDnQjC+j2e-kBQA) and click **RUN**.

You can learn more about Generic Type Variables [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#working-with-generic-type-variables) and [here](https://mattferderer.com/difference-between-array-types-in-typescript)

Comment: @Nima What's wrong with my answer? I corrected his code (answering how to push an object to array in TypeScript) and explained about how to use Generic Type Variables to learn more about this kind of staff.

Comment: @Nima You can read my updated answer and I added a link to TypeScript Playground with edited code to show you that my answer works.

Comment: 1. Actually there is no different between `Array<...>` and `Comment[]` from OP question! 2. `dish.comment.push{/*all fields of Comment with value should work*/});` 3. my playgound link is too long that I cannot put it in here ....

Answer (score 6):

If you simply need to add the new `commentData` after each form submission (if I understood you correctly), all you need is this every time you want the new comments to be pushed to the existing `dish.comments`,

```
this.dish.comments = this.dish.comments.push(this.commentData); // assuming these are class properties, hence the 'this' usage
```

Does that work for you?

**EDIT**

Modify the first line

```
this.commentData = this.comment.value;
```

in `dismiss()` method to this,

```
this.commentData.author = this.comment.get('author').value;
this.commentData.rating = this.comment.get('rating').value;
this.commentData.comment = this.comment.get('comment').value;
```

Comment: Yes, that's what i want but it's not working. 
[ts] Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Comment[]'.
(property) Dish.comments: Comment[]

Comment: Interesting, where does the `number` come from? Can you show an example of your commentData object?

Comment: Sample of commentData object.   `{
          "rating": 5,
          "comment": "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
          "author": "John Lemon",
          "date": "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },`

Comment: If either of your models (interfaces) don't exactly match to their respective objects, then this error can happen. May be you have to check your object structure and 'optionalize' certain properties in the interface declaration using the `?` symbol like, for ex: `rating?: number;`

Comment: This 's my git https://github.com/zymethyang/Ionic_HKUST. Could you help me fix it. This is  dismiss() method on comment.ts. Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer. See if that helps.

Comment: Nice! Could you please mark this answer if it helped you solve it.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to add multiple objects to an array inside a loop:

```
let thingsArray = [];

someArray.forEach(doc => {
    let thingsObj = {} as Thingy;

    thingsObj.weekDue = doc.name;
    thingsObj.title = doc.age;
    thingsArray.push(thingsObj);

}).then(() => {
    console.log(thingsArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`let arraylist= [];`
   `let obj1 =  {} as Class;`
   `obj1.id = 1;`
   `obj1.name = 'text';`
   `let obj2 =  {} as Class;`
   `obj2.id = 1;`
   `obj2.name = 'text';`
   `arraylist =[obj1,obj2 ];`

This work for me but I tried it with Classes